# How to use same Div element for more than one Route in React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently I'm using react 18 and React-Router 6. I've 100s of `Route` components and I need to same `div` for all of them.

For example

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="route1" element={
    <div className={`test flex flex-col`}>
      <Home Component />
      <Route path='/route2' element={<ChildComponent1 />} />
      <Route path='/route3' element={<ChildComponent2 />} />
    </div>
  } 
  />
</Routes>
```

When I use above code then the error shows: `A Route is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your Route in a Routes`.

When I change my code like below it works but need to write `div` again and again.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="route1" element={
    <div className={`test flex flex-col`}>
      <Home Component />
    </div>
  />
  <Route path="route2" element={
    <div className={`test flex flex-col`}>
      <ChildComponent1 />
    </div>
  />
  <Route path="route3" element={
    <div className={`test flex flex-col`}>
      <ChildComponent2 />
    </div>
  } 
</Routes>
```

Is there any way to use all the component in single div with different component?